# Hangman game in javascript shows script busy or not responding dialog box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a hangman game made in css, javascript and html. It seemed to be working fine (over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336880/how-to-deal-with-repeated-letters-in-a-javascript-hangman-game) when I asked an earlier question) but now it seems to be giving this error in a dialog box:

> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding.
>   You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script
>   will complete.
>
> Script: http://fiddle.jshell.net/h_i_r_a/5rtwed1d/19/show/:200

The change I made was calculating the number of repeated letters (or rather the number for extra letters for example 2 in case of the word 'letters' or 4 in case of 'leettters') in a repeatedLetter() function. This is needed for me to calculate when the word has been correctly guessed in the statement ( if ((totalCorrectClicks + letterRep)  == word.length)) in the code.

Could anyone please help ? Thanks!

Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="hangman">
      <div id="stand"></div>
      <div id="face"></div>
      <div id="body"></div>
      <div id="left-arm"></div>
      <div id="right-arm"></div>
      <div id="left-leg"></div>
      <div id="right-leg"></div>

    </div>
    <div id="alphabet">

    </div>
      <p id="gameOver"></p>

    <div id="beingGuessedWord"></div>



  </div>
   <button id="play" onclick="reloadPage()"></button>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
#play {
  position:relative;
  left:510px;
  top:-450px;
  visibility:hidden;

}

#container {
  height:450px; 
  width:600px;
  border:3px solid black; 
  border-radius:5px;
  background-color:hsla(327, 100%, 15%, 1);
  position:relative;  

}

#stand {

  background-image:url('http://i59.tinypic.com/sbll48.png');
  height:220px;
  width:200px;

 }

#face {
  background-image:url('http://i59.tinypic.com/6dx0ee.png');
  height:60px;
  width:60px;
  position:relative;
  top:-175px;
  left:155px;
  visibility:hidden;  



}

#body {
background-image:url('http://i61.tinypic.com/27ywcg.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position:relative;
  height:50px;
  top:-175px;
  left:155px;
  visibility:hidden;  

}

#left-arm {
  background-image:url('http://i58.tinypic.com/2evvvac.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position:relative;
  height:70px;
  width:40px;
  top:-240px;
  left:150px;
  visibility:hidden;  


}

#right-arm{
  background-image:url('http://i58.tinypic.com/vfuhyp.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position:relative;
  height:70px;
  width:40px;
  top:-300px;
  left:190px;
   visibility:hidden;  

}

#left-leg{
  background-image:url('http://i57.tinypic.com/t4u5na.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position:relative;
  height:60px;
  width:60px;
  top:-335px;
  left:135px;
  visibility:hidden;  

}

#right-leg{
  background-image:url('http://i61.tinypic.com/2dqplzb.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position:relative;
  height:50px;
  width:60px;
  top:-385px;
  left:180px;
  visibility:hidden; 

}

#alphabet {
  height:100px;
  width:250px;
  position:relative;
  top:-450px;
  left:300px;
  text-align:center;

}

#alphabet a {
  font-size:25px;
  text-decoration:none;
  margin:5px;
  font-family: 'Courgette', cursive;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:hsla(327, 13%, 28%, 1);

}

#alphabet a:hover {
  color:hsla(327, 13%, 54%, 1);

}

#beingGuessedWord {
  height:70px;
  width:515px;

  position:relative;
  top:-550px;
  padding-top:20px;


}

.letterp {
  border:2px solid black;
  font-family:"Courgette", cursive;
  font-size:22px;
  margin:10px;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding:5px;
  border-radius:5px;


}

#dash {
  padding:5px;
  margin:5px;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:serif;

}

#gameOver {


 font-family:'Courgette', cursive;
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:bold;
 position:relative;
 top:-670px;
 left:300px;
 height:70px;
 width:280px;   
 border-radius:5px;
 text-align:center;   
 visibility:hidden;      


}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var totalIncorrectClicks = 0;//Global variables
var totalCorrectClicks = 0;

var repeatedLetters = function(word) {

var count = 0;
var letterRep = 0;

while (count < word.length)
{
    var letter = word[count];

    var localInstance = (word.split(letter).length - 1) ;
   if ( localInstance > 1)
   {
    count = count + localInstance;
    letterRep = letterRep + (word.split(letter).length - 1) - 1;  
   }

   if (localInstance == 1)
   {
       count = count++;
   }

}
  return letterRep;
}

var reloadPage = function() {
    location.reload();
}

var clickLetter = function() {


 var clickedLetter = document.getElementById(this.id); 
  var tempWord = localStorage["wordGuess"];
  /////////////
  var word = new String();
  for (var k=0; k<tempWord.length;k++)
    {
      if (k%2 === 0 )
        {
          word = word + tempWord[k];

        }
    }



    var compareSuccess = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {

      if (word[i] == clickedLetter.innerHTML) 
      {

          var pId = "pid" + (i+1);


          var pNode = document.getElementById(pId);
          pNode.style.visibility = "visible";
          compareSuccess = true;

      }

    }
    if (compareSuccess == true)
      {
        totalCorrectClicks++; 
      }
   var letterRep = repeatedLetters(word);

    if ((totalCorrectClicks + letterRep)  == word.length)
      {
        var gameOver = document.getElementById('gameOver');
        gameOver.innerHTML = "Well Done!";
        gameOver.style.visibility = "visible";
        var playButton = document.getElementById('play');
        playButton.style.visibility = "visible";
      }

    if (compareSuccess == false)
    {
        totalIncorrectClicks++;
    }

    if (compareSuccess === false && totalIncorrectClicks <=7)
    {
        if (totalIncorrectClicks == 1)
        {
        var face = document.getElementById('face');
        face.style.visibility = "visible";
        }

         if (totalIncorrectClicks == 2)
        {
        var body = document.getElementById('body');
        body.style.visibility = "visible";
        }

         if (totalIncorrectClicks == 3)
        {
        var leftArm = document.getElementById('left-arm');
        leftArm.style.visibility = "visible";
        }

         if (totalIncorrectClicks == 4)
        {
        var rightArm = document.getElementById('right-arm');
        rightArm.style.visibility = "visible";
        }

         if (totalIncorrectClicks == 5)
        {
        var leftLeg = document.getElementById('left-leg');
        leftLeg.style.visibility = "visible";
        }

         if (totalIncorrectClicks == 6)
        {
        var rightLeg = document.getElementById('right-leg');
        rightLeg.style.visibility = "visible";
        }

        if (totalIncorrectClicks == 7)
        {
            var gameOver = document.getElementById('gameOver');
            gameOver.innerHTML = "Game Over!" + "<br>" +
              "The word is: " + word + "<br>" + "(PS: I am not actually being hanged!)";


            gameOver.style.visibility = "visible";
             var playButton = document.getElementById('play');
        playButton.style.visibility = "visible";

        }
    }


}

var createAlphabets = function () {
  var alphabets = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

for (var i = 0; i < alphabets.length; i++)
  {
    var anchorNode = document.createElement('a');
    var idanch = "id" + (i+1);


    anchorNode.setAttribute('id', idanch);


    anchorNode.innerHTML = alphabets[i];

    anchorNode.setAttribute('href', "#");


    var alphaDiv = document.getElementById('alphabet');

    alphaDiv.appendChild(anchorNode);

    if (i == 11 || i == 22)
      {
        alphaDiv.innerHTML = alphaDiv.innerHTML + "<br>";

      }


  }
}

var selectWord = function() {

  var wordArray = ["lamprophony", "ethereal", "sun", "clouds", "evanescent", "munchkin", "exultant", "limerance", "segue", "serendipity", "ineffable", "transcendent"];
  var randomWord = wordArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordArray.length)];
  var splitRandomWord = randomWord.split('');

  return splitRandomWord;

}


var displayWord  = function(word) {


  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {


    var dispWordDiv = document.getElementById('beingGuessedWord');


    var pNode = document.createElement('p');

    pNode.innerHTML = word[i];
    var id = "pid" + (i+1);

    pNode.setAttribute('id', id);
    pNode.setAttribute('class', "letterp");  
      pNode.style.visibility = "hidden";
      pNode.style.display = "inline-block";

    dispWordDiv.appendChild(pNode);

  }

  var dispWordDiv  = document.getElementById('beingGuessedWord');
  dispWordDiv.innerHTML = dispWordDiv.innerHTML + "<br>"; 

  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      var dispWordDiv  = document.getElementById('beingGuessedWord');
      var empty = document.createElement('p');
      empty.setAttribute('id', 'dash');
      empty.innerHTML = "___";
      empty.style.display = "inline";



    dispWordDiv.appendChild(empty);
  }
  }

  var word = selectWord();
  createAlphabets();
  displayWord(word);
  for (var i = 0; i < 27 ; i++) {
  var id = "id" + ( i + 1 );
  var anchor  = document.getElementById(id);
  localStorage["wordGuess"] = word; 

  anchor.onclick = clickLetter;
}
```

JFiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/h_i_r_a/5rtwed1d/20/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point localInstance == 0 so count is not incrementing, try doing

```
if (localInstance <= 1)
{
    count = count++;
}
```

instead of

```
if (localInstance == 1)
{
    count = count++;
}
```

That should stop the freezing.

Comment: Thanks! Its not freezing anymore!

Answer (score 1):

Your loop never ends when localinstance is 0.